# Comparing three numbers with the Java logical-ternary operator?

Tags: java, logic, ternary-operator

I'm trying to create a method that returns the smallest value of three values (all bytes). Here is what I have:

```
public static byte findSmallestOfThree(byte n1, byte n2, byte n3) {
    return n1 > n2 ? n2 : n1 > n3 ? n3 : n1;
}
```

Now, the issue I'm having is that it doesn't always work.

Here are some inputs, and the outputs:

```
9, 10, 11 -> 9

10, 9, 11 -> 9

10, 11, 9 -> 9

11, 10, 9 -> 10
```

As you can see, when I entered 11, 10, 9 (in that order), I got 10 as the result (even though it should have been 9).

What is wrong with my logic? I think I've messed something up with the ternary operators, but I'm not sure what it is...

Comment: I love the ternary op as much as the next guy; but this garble of ascii is a good illustration of why ternaries shouldn't be chained like this. Sure, I *could* sit here, pretend to be javacc and figure out what nesting goes where... but I would much rather just see a few if-elses that relieve me of that duty. The other answers here indicate that you got mentally mixed up with your comparisons; it's pretty easy to do that when you try to do too much in one statement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a mistake with the ternary operators; it's a mistake with the comparisons.  Your code says: if n1 > n2, return n2.  So in the fourth example, 11 > 10, so it returns 10.

You have to compare n1 to both n2 and n3 to know that it's the greatest or lowest. You really want something like

```
return (n1 <= n2) && (n1 <= n3) ? n1 : (n2 <= n3)? n2 : n3
```

(note: not actually tested)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (I made them `int` for easier testing):

```
public static int findSmallestOfThree(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    return n1 < n2 ? n1 < n3 ? n1 : n3 : n2 < n3 ? n2 : n3;
}
```

If you care more about readability than speed:

```
public static int findSmallestOfThree(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    return Math.min(n1, Math.min(n2, n3));
}
```

Here's some simple test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(9, 10, 11));
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(10, 9, 11));
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(10, 11, 9));
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(11, 10, 9));
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(9, 11, 10));
    System.out.println(findSmallestOfThree(11, 9, 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte min = n1 < n2 ? n1 : n2;
return min < n3 ? min : n3;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the max value out of three numbers, one line method:

**int min = (a < b && a < c) ? a : ((b < a && b < c) ? b : c);**

Answer (score 0):

Code to find the greatest of three numbers using ternary operator:

```
public class FindGraterUsingTernaryOperator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the 3 Numbers to Check the Grater:::");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    int result = c > (a > b ? a : b) ? c : ((a > b) ? a : b);
    System.out.println("Grater Between 3 Numbers Is::" + result);
  }
}
```